# Jade select options

Tags: pug

I want to set values to a options in select, but it doesn't work here is my code:

```
div(class="input-group")
                    span(class="input-group-addon")
                        i(class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase")
                    select(class="selectpicker form-control" id="cmbEmpresa")
                        option(value=0) Seleccione Empresa
                        each e in emps
                            //- console.log(e.clave)
                            opcion(value=e.id) #{e.clave}
```

any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be due to a typo: You have `opcion` instead of `option` on the last line.